# Executing bash command (with root access) inside nodejs app

Tags: javascript, node.js, bash

I have an little problem here.
I have nodejs app that should run command in OS's bash with root rights, f.e.

Command is:
**echo "$password" | /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/abc --key "$username"**

Here is my code:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;
function sendMessage() {
    let username = 'WhoLetTheDogsOut';
    let password = 'Woof!';
    const echo = spawn('echo', [ password ]);
    const abc = spawn('sudo', [ `/usr/bin/abc --key ${username}` ]);
}
sendMessage();
```

Please, help. I didn't get where I'm wrong after reading [official Node child_process.spawn() doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options) and I'm keep getting error:
**gnokii stderr: sudo: /usr/bin/gnokii --sendsms +375293941196: command not found**

Comment: Do you mean to have ` around `/usr/bin/abc --key ${username}`? Shouldn't they be '.

Comment: @phreed [template string literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals)

Comment: Do you have gnokii http://gnokii.org/index.shtml installed on your system?

Comment: I do not see where you are tying the std-output of 'echo' to the std-input of 'abc'.

Comment: @phreed Yes, I have installed gnokii. I've thowed out that piece of code, 'cause it's a copypaste from [official nodejs doc](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_spawn_command_args_options).

Comment: ok, I think what is happening is that one of the spawned processes is failing (probably abc as the password is not arriving) and then the gnokii is failing for some other unrelated reason. You need to tie the stdout from echo to the stdin of abc. You should also write out the errors from both echo and abc and post the results.  echo.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
  abc.stdin.write(data);
});

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I hope this will help you , it's a package of NPM "node-cmd", you can run commands in bash with nodejs, Here is an example:

```
var cmd=require('node-cmd');

cmd.get('echo '+password+' | /usr/bin/sudo /usr/bin/abc --key '+username,
    function(data){
        console.log('The result of the command:'+data)
    }
);
```

Remember give permisions (chmod) to the file and run the process like root if you need.

This is the source  https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-cmd

Comment: I'll try it and post result later. Thanks!